# Android NetworkOnMainThreadException inside Asyntask class

Tags: android, exception, networkonmainthread

This code shows the exception when it reach the get sentence (line commented on the code). 
The code is the next, consist on get a comments list from Http get Request:

```
public class ObtencionComentariosPerfil extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<Comment>>{

@Override
protected List<Comment> doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI url;
    List<Comment> listaComentarios = new ArrayList<Comment>();

    try {
        url = new URI(params[1]);
        HttpGet del = new HttpGet(url);
        del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        del.setHeader("X-Auth-Token", params[0]);
        System.out.println("El token params es: "+params[0]);

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);// THE EXCEPTION shows here
        StatusLine estatus = resp.getStatusLine(); 

        if (estatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            InputStream is = resp.getEntity().getContent();
            CommentsParser parser= new CommentsParser();
            listaComentarios = parser.parseoComentarios(is.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
            listaComentarios = null;
        }


    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return listaComentarios;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Comment> lista){

}

}
```

Here is called from main code:

```
public List<Comment> obtieneComentariosPerfil(long idUsuario, String aut){
    List<Comment> listaComentarios = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    String url= "http://"+ip+":8080/api/users/"+idUsuario+"/comments";
    String[] params= new String[2];
    params[0]=aut;
    params[1]=url;
    ObtencionComentariosPerfil du = new ObtencionComentariosPerfil();
    listaComentarios = du.doInBackground(params);

    return listaComentarios;
}
```

I think it have to be a stupid failure but i cant find the error. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't started Async task correctly.  Use AsynTask.execute() for running background task.

Comment: please post complete [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call `du.doInBackground(params);`

you should call `du.excute(params)` instead

Comment: oh my god... im so stupid... I know it... i dont know why i did doInBackground... Im blind...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> listaComentarios = du.doInBackground(params);
> ```

You submit async tasks for execution in a background thread by calling `execute()`, not by directly calling the `doInBackground()` callback in the current thread.

Communicate the result back to UI thread in `onPostExecute()`.